# backtesting.py ploting function not working

Tags: python-3.x, back-testing

I'm trying to learn backtesting.py, when I run the following sample code, it pops up these errors, anyone could help? I tried to uninstall the Bokeh package and reinstall an older version, but it doen't work.

```
BokehDeprecationWarning: Passing lists of formats for DatetimeTickFormatter scales was deprecated in Bokeh 3.0. Configure a single string format for each scale
C:\Users\paul_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\formatters.py:399: UserWarning: DatetimeFormatter scales now only accept a single format. Using the first prodvided: '%d %b'
  warnings.warn(f"DatetimeFormatter scales now only accept a single format. Using the first prodvided: {fmt[0]!r} ")
BokehDeprecationWarning: Passing lists of formats for DatetimeTickFormatter scales was deprecated in Bokeh 3.0. Configure a single string format for each scale
C:\Users\paul_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\formatters.py:399: UserWarning: DatetimeFormatter scales now only accept a single format. Using the first prodvided: '%m/%Y'
  warnings.warn(f"DatetimeFormatter scales now only accept a single format. Using the first prodvided: {fmt[0]!r} ")
GridPlot(id='p11925', ...)
```

```
import bokeh
import datetime
import pandas_ta as ta
import pandas as pd

from backtesting import Backtest
from backtesting import Strategy
from backtesting.lib import crossover
from backtesting.test import GOOG

class RsiOscillator(Strategy):

    upper_bound = 70
    lower_bound = 30
    rsi_window = 14

    # Do as much initial computation as possible
    def init(self):
        self.rsi = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)

    # Step through bars one by one
    # Note that multiple buys are a thing here
    def next(self):
        if crossover(self.rsi, self.upper_bound):
            self.position.close()
        elif crossover(self.lower_bound, self.rsi):
            self.buy()

bt = Backtest(GOOG, RsiOscillator, cash=10_000, commission=.002)
stats = bt.run()
bt.plot()
```

Answer (score 14):

An issue was opened for this in the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/kernc/backtesting.py/issues/803

A comment in the issue suggests to downgrade bokeh to 2.4.3:

```
python3 -m pip install bokeh==2.4.3
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, using Spyder IDE.

Found out I need to call the below for the plot to show for Spyder.

backtesting.set_bokeh_output(notebook=False)

Answer (score 0):

I have update Python to version 3.11 & downgrade bokeh to 2.4.3

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Bokeh didn't work for me.
But, after importing backtesting in Jupyter, I needed to do:
backtesting.set_bokeh_output(notebook=False)

The expected plot was then generated in a new interactive browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

I can produce plots after upgrading to 3.3.0 dev1, which solved my problem temporarily - though I still get the "BokehDeprecationWarning: Passing lists of formats for DatetimeTickFormatter scales was deprecated in Bokeh 3.0."